# Skoda Octavia 5e 2016 184hp losing motor oil

Tags: oil-leak, skoda, octavia

Hello guys I have **Skoda Octavia 5e 2016 kombi** since 2020 February bought it at 125.000 and at start I didn't lose any oil Every 10.000 I change my oil and in 2021 I had one issue what my mechanic told me at 150.000 the seals of top motor place I don't know what's called but it was worn off and the oil leaked in timing belt and I needed to change that and the seals on top of the motor done it and it seemed ok

then now 1 year later I put on 10.000 km additional 1 liter of **5w30** oil because I lose oil now but I don't think it's normal because on normal drive max speed 100 kmh I don't lose anything still but when I do a kickdown or little bit aggressive drive I get a warn lamp to add more oil often then is something off should I check air intake or ? No leaks on motor or under,spark plugs I changed 1 week ago and there was no oil on them or smth else ...does it has inpact when the oil is hot? I mean I don't know if that's normal but normal drive my motor oil is always between 90/105 Celsius but when I drive 140kmh on autobahn it comes to almost 115celsius..

I didn't had this issue before and I don't know if it's normal because I didn't had this before .. now it has **175.000** km and motor type is **CUNA** and I am scared if it is pistons or some bigger damage to stop it before it's to late I am sorry for bad English and long text I am thankful for any advice ..

***EDIT***

**I have 2.0 diesel motor** I forgot to mention that and I have a different question is it normal that the 2.0 diesel motor never sounds same ?
Or ?
This drives me crazy sometimes it sounds almost like a 2000 tractor and sometimes u can't almost hear nothing besides nice noice but sometimes I hear some clicks but local mechanic told me that's normal for those motors ?

Answer (score 0):

Please see [this link](https://www.foxwooddiesel.com/blog/what-causes-high-oil-consumption-in-diesel-engine) for possible causes.